# Re-training regression model on covid data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, boosting

I am trying to re-train a regression model (XGB regressor) which was used in the pre-covid times (Feb 2020).

The dependent variable for the model is the number of bookings done, and due to covid, the bookings have been affected ,hence it will affect the accuracy of my model.

Any suggestions on how I can manage to re-train my model on covid data and still manage to get decent accuracy?

Comment: Add an indicator for the pandemic? Retrain only using pandemic data? How would you solve any other problem of model misfit?